# Occurance of character after specific index

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Is there any way to achieve what JAVA function **int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)** do.

Let me explain it:

```
NSString *steSample = @"This is sample test string";
```

Now i want to get the index of ***i*** but after 2nd index. How can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the regex way is too complicated for me :)

can't we just trim it and then look for it?

that'd be 3 lines...

wrapped in a category:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Extend)
-(NSUInteger)indexOfSubstring:(NSString*)needle afterIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
@implementation NSString (Extend) 
-(NSUInteger)indexOfSubstring:(NSString*)needle afterIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    id str = [self substringFromIndex:index];

    NSUInteger i = [str rangeOfString:needle].location;
    return i==NSNotFound ? i : i+index;
}
@end
```

Demo usage:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        id str = @"@asd@asd";
        NSUInteger index = [str indexOfSubstring:@"@" afterIndex:2];
        NSLog(@"index of @ is: %d", index);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what exactlly I am looking for. awesome !!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
NSString *_sample = @"This is sample test string";
NSError *_error;
NSRegularExpression *_regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"i" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&_error];
NSArray *_matches = [_regExp matchesInString:_sample options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, _sample.length)];
[_matches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * result, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx == 0) {
        NSLog(@"ignoring first occurance...");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"occurance's index : %d, character's index in string : %d", idx, result.range.location); // that line is simplified for your problem
    }
}];
```

*NOTE: you can rearrange the actual `if` statement, it currently 'skips' the first occurance and prints the rest – but it can be customised for your further wish.*

---

my console shows something like this:

```
ignoring first occurance...
occurance's index : 1, character's index in string : 5
occurance's index : 2, character's index in string : 23
```

Comment: find this too complicated -- why do we compile a regex pattern even

Comment: @Daij-Djan, it is complicated to read or to understand or how do you mean?

Comment: actually I meant - too much code for a rather simple task ;) a bit like: "to take a sledgehammer to crack a nut"

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *steSample = @"This is sample test string";
NSUInteger count = 0, length = [steSample length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
while(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    range = [steSample rangeOfString: @"i" options:0 range:range];
    if(range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));

        count++;
        if (count == 2)
        {
            NSLog(@"%d", range.location); // print 6 which is location of second 'i'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The location of the second `i` is 5.  You appear to be modifying `range` after successfully finding the character, but before logging the value.  I was also considering this approach, but I think using `[NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:]` might be less complicated.